# How to insert column values based on another column

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, postgresql

Suppose I have a postgresql table like this:

```
CustomerID | Pincode
```

and another table like this

```
Pincode | City
```

I want to create a new column in the first table name City which maps city from the second one and inserts it.

Final result

```
CustomerID | Pincode | City
```

Please note that the second table contains unique pincode to city mapping while first table can have many pincodes with different customer id (customer id is unique)

How to do it?

If can't be done in the database, then I am ok with python solution as well.

Comment: Please look up Foreign keys in databases.

Comment: Assuming each PIN code is unique, then there may not even be a need for two tables here, in which case your question has nothing to do with Python, but rather with your underlying SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call those tables A and B. SQL query :

```
SELECT A.CustomerID, A.Pincode, B.City
FROM A, B
WHERE A.Pincode = B.Pincode;
```

If data in A is :

1 1

2 2

3 1

5 2

and B:

1 1

2 2

result will be :

1 1 1

2 2 2

3 1 1

5 2 2

Comment: It would be better to do a proper `JOIN` instead of a multi `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table first_table add column City text;

insert into first_table (CustomerID, Pincode, City)
    select ft.CustomerID, at.Pincode, at.City
    from first_table as ft
        join another_table as at on ft.Pincode = at.Pincode
;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to offer the OP some context about what and why you are doing it this way.